# What does "statements of great density" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

The following context comes from the book "Black Rednecks And White Liberals" by Thomas Sowell:

> ""By contrast, religious services in colonial Massachusetts developed what has been called the “meeting and lecture” approach, where the “style of
> preaching was a relentless cultivation of the plain style.” these “addresses tended to be closely argued statements of great **density**, in which Puritans
> reasoned as relentlessly with their maker as they did with one another."
> This intellectual approach to religion carried over into their daily lives.""

Is any of these two senses conveyed here?

> Density (thefreedictionary) 
> 8. **Stupidity**; dullness.

> Density (thefreedictionary) 
> 7. **Complexity** of structure or content.

Comment: The second definition matches the sense of the paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the second meaning does apply. Dense  prose is characterized by great length, the use of numerous unusual or technical terms, and a level of structural complexity that together make it difficult to understand the writing. Some people may write dense  prose to  convey the impression that they are very learned. But if the purpose of writing is to communicate ideas, rather than to burnish a writer's reputation, the writer should avoid dense prose.

Answer (score 2):

You've used a dictionary to find the possible meanings, so you know as much as any native speaker. How would a native speaker determine which it means?

Context.

Given that the text goes on to speak about these 'dense' statements as an "intellectual approach", I would not assume it means they were stupid.